# Binary Security Token from p12 vs Binary Security Token from jks

Tags: c#, .net, soap, x509certificate, jks

I need to obtain the BinarySecurityToken to authenticate to Soap WebApi, I know that BinarySecurityToken is certificate content encoded in Base64. When I test api in SoapUI the Binary sec token is generated from jks file from my certificate, everything works. The problem is when I need to connect to api form C# then I am using p12 cert and getting encoded base64 content of cert like in jks file but the values are different and BinarySecurityToken from p12 is not working with Soap api.

Conclusion: BinarySecToken generated from jks is different than generated from p12.

Is there any way to generate BinarySecToken as same as from jks file? 
Is any way to work with jks files in c# ?

This is how I get the BinarySecToken:

```
           X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath,"pass");

           var content = cert.RawData;

           var base64content = Convert.ToBase64String(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

BinarySecurityToken in `.jks` file is raw content data but with one difference. Token in jks file contains file size at the begining, token data generated from `.p12` is the same data as `jks` but without file size. In my solution I solve it in other way. I think there is no solutions when you need to obtain BinarySecurityToken from file as raw data. There are other api mechanism that will solve it for you. When you want to obtain token as raw data from file, you do it something wrong and for sure that won't solve your issue.